About the formula $\;\pi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2n+1}\cos^{2n+1}x-\sin2x+2x$, with $a_0=4$, $a_1=-2$, and $a_n=\frac{3-2n}{n!\,2^{n-2}}$
Here's something I found while playing around with Newton's approach to calculate $\pi$. This converges faster for $x$ close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. $$\pi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2n+1}\cos ^{2n+1}x-\sin2x + 2x$$ where $$a_0 = 4, \quad a_1 = -2, \quad a_n = \frac{3-2n}{n!\times2^{n-2}}$$This converges to $\pi$ only for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$
Basically, I generalized Newton's approach for any angle. So, of course, it converges faster for $x$ close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. But, for some reason, it doesn't converge as fast as I thought it would. Can we somehow take the limit as $x$ goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and get a more efficient formula?
I learned about Newton's approach from Veritasium's YouTube video "The Discovery That Transformed Pi".
I think this series would be easy to calculate by hand (even though no one does it anymore) as we can approximate $\sin x$ for small $x$ using Taylor Series' and then we get $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - x).$

Also, could we try to compute $\pi$ to high accuracy with this? Can someone tell me how fast it converges?

Unless something is missing, the RHS doesn't seem to approach $\pi$

@HazemOrabi That's my question

There is hopefully a connection with Chebyshev polynomials expressing $\cos(n x)$ in terms of powers of cosine $(\cos x)^k$...

@JeanMarie Can you please check how fast its convergence is and how its error compounds?

Sorry, I haven't much time at present...

With @Claude Leibovici's comment, the RHS cannot equal $\pi$ unless $x=\pi/2$. However, the remainder is at $O(\cos(x)^9)$ when expanding into the Taylor series. Here is a plot of the error https://imgur.com/a/cXo5Fma

As I said, the comment is incorrect.

@Yimin Look at the question carefully.

Too long for a comment.
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3-2n}{n!\,\,2^{n-2}}\,t^{2n+1}=4 t \left(e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} \left(3-t^2\right)-3\right)$$ If you let $t=\cos(x)$ and expand around $x=\frac \pi 2$, the right hand side you wrote is
$$\pi +\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 n-1}$$  where the first $a_n$ are
$$\left\{4,-\frac{10}{3},\frac{53}{30},-\frac{103}{252},
-\frac{4657}{90720},\frac{99353}{1995840},-
   \frac{9062917}{1556755200},-\frac{167418343}{65383718400},\cdots\right\}$$

I don't get it.

@AkshajMishra. It is just a comment for an interesting problem

But if you expanded around $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, why is it still in the rhs?

And how did you get $a_n$

@AkshajMishra. This is Taylor series

Oh right. I am very sorry. I didn't notice it at first.

This isn't very helpful.

Using this, one can derive the approx error of the series already,
